# What's the difference between an "R Project" and "R Package Project" in Eclipse StatET?

Tags: eclipse, r, statet

It seems the Eclipse R add-on StatET, has two difference kinds of R Projects. What are the differences between these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new type of a project, useful when you're debugging your package from source (as of late, StatET has debugging capabilities, too). See some [comments from the author](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/statet-user/2011-November/001103.html) of StatET from about a month ago.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the passage I was looking for:

"For your own packages that you develop within Eclipse, you
should create an R Package Project (and set the root and
name of the package correctly). An R Package Project is a
new type of Project (other than the plain 'R Project').

If you then install the package from within Eclipse (using
the R CMD tools inside your R package project (by selecting
the root folder of the package and invoking R CMD INSTALL on
it), you will be able to debug within the package namespace."